# How can I add multiple tables of data source in Google Data Studio?

Tags: postgresql, looker-studio

I want to connect my data source which is a PostgreSQL database containing more than 80+ tables in it. I need these tables to generate different reports, but the issue is I can't find any way to import more than one table at a time.

If I need to make 40 reports using 40 different tables inside of the same data source, do I need to create 40 new connections each time to get a new table?

I know we can have multiple data sources but in my case, I just have one source with many tables!

Answer (score 0):

**Data sources represent a particular instance of a connector;** a single PostgreSQL Table creates a single Google Data Studio Data Source, thus 40 PostgreSQL Tables would require 40 Data Sources ([reference link](https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/36883101/loading-multiple-tables-to-gds-using-postgresql-connector?hl=en)).

But we can still do something like creating a custom sql query, instead of connecting single table ([Google Support answer](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article)).